# How to start celerycam with fabric in background

Tags: background, celery, fabric

I use this command

sudo('/usr/bin/python /project/manage.py celerycam &')

and it's seem not to work fine. It does not run celerycam on the server that fabric completed its task.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use the '--detach' argument instead?

```
/project/manage.py celerycam --detach --pidfile=/project/cam.pid --logfile=/project/cam.log
```

Or even better, use the celeryevcam init script: https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/contrib/generic-init.d/celeryevcam